# how to call a html page from spring boot application

Tags: java, html, servlets, spring-boot

I have tried using servlet , but it is not working.
web.xml :

```
<display-name>Password</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SetPassword</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.cx.view.SetPassword</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SetPassword</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/view/setPassword</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have a HTML page in [email_templates/setPassword.html]

java code :

```
public class SetPassword extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7514856921920494774L;

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
            .getRequestDispatcher("email_templates/setPassword.html");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

//tried for both get and post request

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
            .getRequestDispatcher("email_templates/setPassword.html");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

}

Url trying to access: http://localhost:8080/view/setPassword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot [serves automatically](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) static resources from one of these directories:

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

So try to save your page in one of these folders (I would suggest /static/ or /public/)

Comment: My html page is in /resources/email_templates/setPassword.html

Comment: I don't get what you really want to do. Static resources are servered from one one of the directories above. If you want to register a new Servlet and access this then you can use a [ServletRegistrationBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletRegistrationBean.html).